# Do good comments lead to reputation for post authors?

Tags: discussion, comments, voting

I sometimes see cases where a comment praising an answer is posted under the answer or the question, and then that answer gets a lot more votes.  It seems that the presence of the comment influences voters.  Perhaps I'm mistaken, but because of this, it makes me think that comments are a subtle way of gleaning points.  Is this actually the case?  Do comments from fans boost reputation?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by phantom points.  Could you point out an example?

Comment: Do you mean that a good comment can influence the voting?

Comment: I've made a major edit based on your comments.  Is that what you meant to ask?  If not, please feel free to roll back my edit.  If you do, it'd be great if you could clarify in an [edit] of your own.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In general comments are not meant to endorse a post. Nor are comments in any way mandatory to accompany a vote.

Comments are there to ask for clarification or to point out issues with a post. I would in the majority of the cases expect (a lot of) comments on posts that have an issue.

However, it certainly is possible that a useful comment can influence voting on a post, both up and down. The comment itself, nor the score of a comment, will result in direct reputation gain or loss.

Keep in mind that certain comments are known to achieve the opposite effect of what was intended, specially when related to voting.

You could do some [querying](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/771525) against the database to see if high scoring comments help in getting votes:

```sql
select top 1000
       c.postid  as [Post Link]
     , count(*) as [number of votes]
from comments c
inner join votes v on v.postid = c.postid 
where v.creationdate between c.creationdate and dateadd(d, 2, c.creationdate) 
and c.score > 10
and v.votetypeid = 2
group by c.postid
order by count(*) desc
```

but I'm not a <s>liar</s> statistician so I leave any conclusions to them.

Comment: @robin comments are meant to be temporary. In the early days of the site design it was even considered to have no comments at all. Just good/ quality questions and their answers. When comments will gain reputation we'll see a lot more of them which has negative impact on the signal/noise ratio and opens other cans of worms, like spammer gaining easy reputation. You might go over some more [FAQ]'s and maybe the [early podcasts](https://stackoverflow.blog/?s=podcast) to get some more insight why things are how they are around the SE network.